# Uniqueness of distribution with moments $M_n$ if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{M_n}$ finite

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, power-series, characteristic-functions

There's a theorem which states that the moments, i.e. $M_n  = \mathbb{E}\left(X^n\right)$, of a distribution uniquely identify the distribution if $$
  R := \left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{M_n}\right)^{-1} > 0 \text{.}
$$

The proof for this that I'm looking at argues this by observing that this condition implies the convergence of the following series expansion of the moment-generating function $$
  M(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty M_n \frac{t^n}{n!}
$$
on $(-R,R)$ (note that $\sqrt[n]{n!} \leq n$). It then asserts that since $\phi(t) = M(it)$, where $\phi$ is the characteristic function and $M$ the moment-generating function of some random variable $X$, this defines the characteristik function, which is known to define the distribution uniquely.

---

My problems with that reasoning is that as far as I can see $M$ *only* defines $\phi$ on $M$'s radius of convergence, i.e. $(-R,R)$. Who's to say that there couldn't be two different extensions $\phi_1$,$\phi_2$ which both agree with $M(it)$ on $(-R,R)$? If I knew $\phi$ to be analytically extendable to the simply connected region $$
   \{t + i\delta\,:\, |\delta| < \epsilon, t \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$ (i.e., a stripe around the real axis), then such an extension would be unique, and that would preclude the possibility of $\phi_1 \neq \phi_2$. But I don't see why such an extension would need to exist. Since I'm starting from (except for the growth condition) arbitrary moments, a priori I don't even know that there's *any* distribution with those moments. And even if I did, I'd only know that there's some $\phi'$ which agrees with $\phi$ on $[0,R)$, not necessarily on $[0,R)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I have the feeling that I'm overlooking some crucial property of $\phi$, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured this out.

Let $F$ be a possible distribution function of $X$. We know that the moment-generating function $M(t) = \mathbb{E_F}e^{Xt}$ is uniquely defined and analytic on a ball with radius $R$ around zero. Then characteristic function $\phi_F(z) = \mathbb{E_F}e^{iXz}$ then exists on a stripe $S$ with width $R$ around the real axis, because if $z = t - ir$ with $|r| < R$ then $$
       \left|\phi_F(z)\right|
     = 
       \left|\int_\mathbb{R} e^{ix(t-ir)} \,dF \right|
  \leq \int_\mathbb{R} \left|e^{ix(t-ir)}\right| \,dF
  \leq \int_\mathbb{R} e^{xr} \,dF
     = M(r)
     < \infty \text{.}
$$

In other words, $x \to e^{ixz}$ is $F$-integrable for all $z\in S$. Now since $z \to e^{ixz}$ is analytic for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and since $(z,x) \to e^{ixz}$ is
continuous and thus measurable on $S\times\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\phi_F(z)$ is analytic on $S$ (see [Sufficient conditions for $z \to \int_\mathbb{R} h(z,x) \,d\mu(x)$ to be analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387165)).

Since two different $\phi_{F_1}$, $\phi_{F_2}$ agree on the ball with radius $R$ around zero, by the uniqueness of analytic extensions to simply connected regions they must in fact agree on $S$, hence $F_1 = F_2$.

---

The approach Davide Giraudo suggested works too, of course, but the computations get a bit messier. This approach avoids avoids all nicely by referring to the theorem about analytic extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the power series of exponential function and the fact that for $|z|<R/2$, the sequence $(M_n\frac{z^n}{n!},n\geqslant 1)$ is bounded, one can define a power series (hence an holomorphic function) on $B(0,R/2)$ which extends $\phi$. This proves that the values of $\phi$ are determined on a non degenerate interval.

Now the last thing to check is that if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables *having moments of all orders* such that there exists $\delta>0$ for which $E[e^{itX}]=E[e^{itY}]$ if $|t|<\delta$, then actually equality holds for all $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks! I kind of had figured out the first part, i.e. that I get a holomorphic function on a bounded part of the stripe, but had thought it buys me nothing. Which was because I didn't think the second paragraph was true, i.e. if two characteristic functions disagree, they disagree on every interval around $0$. That still confuses me a bit, because the reverse transform does seem to evaluate $\phi$ on the whole real line. I'll go and try to see why the second paragraph is true...

Comment: I'm ended up using a slightly different approach. The statement in your second paragraph doesn't hold unconditionally, I think - in general, on *can* find characteristic functions which agree around $0$ but not on the whole real line. They cannot be *analytic* around zero then, though. I've thus tried to show that $phi$ is analytic on a strip around the real axis first, which seems to work. If you're interested, see the answer I just posted. And thanks for your help! Your answer brought me onto the right track.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to wrote the assumption that the random variables have moments of infinite order. There are counter-example for random variable which are only integrable for example. This explains why you didn't manage to prove the last statement.